# I got Stuck with improving the performance of my SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I got stuck with improving the performance of my query. My Query returns all the 54 weeks baseline data for each Product in a single row as show in the figure below.

```
SELECT BusinessPlanMain.Id, BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg, ProductMain.MetaType, ProductMain.Id [Product ID], BplText.Text, BusinessPlanData.Week1, BusinessPlanData.Week2
                .
                .
                .
 , BusinessPlanData.Week54, SystemPeriod.Year
  FROM BusinessPlanMain INNER JOIN SystemPeriod ON BusinessPlanMain.SystemPeriodPKey = SystemPeriod.PKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanData ON BusinessPlanMain.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanMainPKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanDataTemplate ON BusinessPlanDataTemplate.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanDataTemplatePKey INNER JOIN BplText ON BplText.ReferencePKey=BusinessPlanTemplate.PKey INNER JOIN ProductMain ON BusinessPlanData.ProductMainPKey=ProductMain.PKey WHERE SystemPeriod.Year IN ('2016') AND SystemPeriod.PeriodType = 'Year' AND SystemPeriod.SalesOrg = 'OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg='OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanData.OrgID ='OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanTemplate.Sheet='Baseline' and ProductMain.MetaType IN ('PrdGroup','Product')
```

[The Result of the above Query is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNu4t.png)

I have a requirement in my project to create a DataView where i have to transpose all the 54 weeks column data into a single column as shown in the image below which i have achieved by using 'Union All' keyword 54 times for the above query.

I am looking for a better solution to improve my query performance and neglect 54 times unions. Thanks in advance and any better solution can be appreciated.

```
SELECT BusinessPlanMain.Id
 , BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg
 , ProductMain.MetaType 
 , ProductMain.Id [Product ID]
 , BplText.Text
 , BusinessPlanData.Week1
 , SystemPeriod.Year
  FROM BusinessPlanMain INNER JOIN SystemPeriod ON BusinessPlanMain.SystemPeriodPKey = SystemPeriod.PKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanData ON BusinessPlanMain.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanMainPKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanDataTemplate ON BusinessPlanDataTemplate.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanDataTemplatePKey INNER JOIN BplText ON BplText.ReferencePKey=BusinessPlanTemplate.PKey INNER JOIN ProductMain ON BusinessPlanData.ProductMainPKey=ProductMain.PKey WHERE  SystemPeriod.Year IN ('2016') AND SystemPeriod.PeriodType = 'Year' AND  SystemPeriod.SalesOrg = 'OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg='OrgID1' AND    BusinessPlanData.OrgID ='OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanTemplate.Sheet='Baseline' and   ProductMain.MetaType IN ('PrdGroup','Product') Union ALL SELECT BusinessPlanMain.Id
 , BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg
 , ProductMain.MetaType 
 , ProductMain.Id [Product ID]
 , BplText.Text
 , BusinessPlanData.Week2
 , SystemPeriod.Year
  FROM BusinessPlanMain INNER JOIN SystemPeriod ON BusinessPlanMain.SystemPeriodPKey = SystemPeriod.PKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanData ON BusinessPlanMain.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanMainPKey INNER JOIN BusinessPlanDataTemplate ON BusinessPlanDataTemplate.PKey = BusinessPlanData.BusinessPlanDataTemplatePKey INNER JOIN BplText ON BplText.ReferencePKey=BusinessPlanTemplate.PKey INNER JOIN ProductMain ON BusinessPlanData.ProductMainPKey=ProductMain.PKey WHERE SystemPeriod.Year IN ('2016') AND SystemPeriod.PeriodType = 'Year' AND
SystemPeriod.SalesOrg = 'OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanMain.SalesOrg='OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanData.OrgID ='OrgID1' AND BusinessPlanTemplate.Sheet='Baseline' and ProductMain.MetaType IN ('PrdGroup','Product')
.
.
.
```

Continue 54 Unions

[The Result of the above Query is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IAuZ.jpg)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: "My Query returns all the 54 weeks" - there are 54 weeks in a year?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mitch Wheat. Please consider the total weeks to be 52 in a year.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you will want to use rather than all of these UNION subqueries is called UNPIVOT.  Here is a rough example using your original query -- you will need to research the subject and correct the code below:

```
WITH OriginalDataSet as (
   [your first query here]
)

SELECT ods.Id
 , ods.SalesOrg
 , ods.MetaType 
 , ods.[Product ID]
 , ods.Text
 , ods.SystemPeriod
 , BusinessPlanWeek
 , BusinessPlanWeekData
FROM OriginalDataSet ods
UNPIVOT (BusinessPlanWeekData FOR BusinessPlanWeek In
([Week 1], [Week 2], [Week 3], [Week 4], [Week 5], ...)) AS unpvt
```